# My garden is still mud, and it's 2 weeks after the normal last frost, should I plant seeds yet?

Tags: vegetables, watering, planting

I've read that I should plant seeds 2 weeks after the last expected frost date, but my garden is sill drenched, should I plant them right away, or wait for high water levels to fall (should be by May 1st)?

The only reason why I ask is because I've read to plant beans 2 weeks after the last expected frost, but due to my garden location it's heavily dependent on when my water level isn't high, since the creek it's next to always has water in it.

Comment: It depends on the seeds. If it only beans (and BTW most of seeds), I would say it is too early. I think celery is more tolerant, but I doesn't know, I do not have such problem. Consider to improve your garden (move some soil up, check if you need to build some drainage, etc.) But that is an other question.

Comment: I guess it depends on the type of beans, but in the UK it is common to plant broad bean seeds in October / November to start them growing before winter, and avoid poor weather conditions in spring interfering with planting or germination. But US web sites all seem to claim beans will die at the first touch of frost...

Comment: @alephzero if we did that the bean plants would freeze

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi that's not happening as it's very similar to the principles of tillage

Comment: Try taking a picture of your garden and posting it. What do you mean by your garden is still mud? What do you mean by drenched?

Comment: the high water table = my garden soil level, and am expecting it to drop 1-2' by mothers day